# Authors names and affiliation

Tags: packages, titles, affiliation

Which packages can be using for writing authors names and affiliation?                      thank you in advance

Comment: author of the current document or author of a cited work. (I'm guessing the latter from your tags, but your question is massively unclear)

Comment: Use `authblk`...

Comment: thank you, for the purpose of writing paper and to write the authors names in the first page

Comment: commands to input the author and affiliation are almost always provided by the document class you are using.  check the documentation for the class.

Comment: Isthat means that I do not need to use any extra packages to defines authors

Comment: No, you don't need any packages. You can use package `url` to write email addresses, but the rest will most likely be plain text.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to achieve, a few helpful comments might be included in [How to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/209993)